# GitLab CE: How to upgrade

Tags: gitlab, upgrade

I recently installed GitLib-CE (specifically version 14.1.2) on Ubuntu 22.04. I was running through software updates and an upgrade to GitLab failed:

> Preparing to unpack .../gitlab-ce_15.5.2-ce.0_amd64.deb ...
> gitlab preinstall: It seems you are upgrading from major version 14 to major version 15.
> gitlab preinstall: It is required to upgrade to the latest 15.0.x version first before proceeding.
> gitlab preinstall: Please follow the upgrade documentation at https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/update/index.html#upgrade-paths

After reading the documentation on upgrading, https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/update/index.html#upgrade-paths, it appears major upgrades require a specific path. Since I am on 14.1.2, it appears I need to first upgrade to 14.3.6:

> 8.11.Z -> 8.12.0 -> 8.17.7 -> 9.5.10 -> 10.8.7 -> 11.11.8 -> 12.0.12 -> 12.1.17 -> 12.10.14 -> 13.0.14 -> 13.1.11 -> 13.8.8 -> 13.12.15 -> 14.0.12 -> 14.3.6 -> 14.9.5 -> 14.10.Z -> 15.0.Z -> 15.4.0 -> latest 15.Y.Z

Based upon the instructions here: https://packages.gitlab.com/gitlab/gitlab-ce/packages/ubuntu/focal/gitlab-ce_14.3.6-ce.0_arm64.deb

I first ran:

> curl -s https://packages.gitlab.com/install/repositories/gitlab/gitlab-ce/script.deb.sh | sudo bash

Then I ran:

> sudo apt-get install gitlab-ce=14.3.6-ce.0

And I get this result:

> Reading package lists... Done
> Building dependency tree... Done
> Reading state information... Done
> Package gitlab-ce is not available, but is referred to by another package.
> This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
> is only available from another source
> However the following packages replace it:
> gitlab-ee

> E: Version '14.3.6-ce.0' for 'gitlab-ce' was not found

If I run this command:

> sudo apt show gitlab-ce -a
> It appears the only packages are 14.1.2 (installed), 15.5.0, 15.5.1, and 15.5.2. So do I just need to get the following packages in the package repository: 14.3.6 -> 14.9.5 -> 14.10.Z -> 15.0.Z -> 15.4.0 -> latest 15.Y.Z

If so, how do I get these packages in my package repository? If not, what am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone running into the same challenge.

I ended up downloading the deb packages and installing them manually.

Downloaded from here: https://packages.gitlab.com/gitlab/gitlab-ce

Followed the upgrade path here: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/update/index.html#upgrade-paths

Installed deb packages one at a time using gdebi.

I am now on 15.5.2 and everything seems to be checking out OK.

Comment: Thanks for this! Second time I have been here lol.

Answer (score 1):

pay attention to distributions in apt list for gitlab: trusty, focal and if you need for ubuntu 22.04 and the gitlab versions upper 15 - put jammy

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by doing a manual update. First I downloaded it with wget.

```
wget --content-disposition https://packages.gitlab.com/gitlab/gitlab-ce/packages/ubuntu/bionic/gitlab-ce_12.10.5-ce.0_amd64.deb/download.deb
dpkg -i gitlab-ce_12.10.5-ce.0_amd64.deb
```

then I installed it with dkpg.(don't forget to do a minor version upgrade when upgrading).

```
dpkg -i gitlab-ce_16.3.3-ce.0_amd64.deb
```